# Scrapy yield callback not firing the specified method

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, scrapy

so i have the following code using scrapy:

```
class UnicefpubsSpider(Spider):
    name = 'unicefpubs'
    allowed_domains = ['www.unicef-irc.org']
    start_urls = ['https://www.unicef-irc.org/publications/']
    max_pages = 0

    custom_settings = {
        # 'LOG_ENABLED': False,
        'ROBOTSTXT_OBEY': False,
        'DOWNLOAD_DELAY': 5,
        'RETRY_TIMES': 5,
        'RETRY_HTTP_CODES': [500, 502, 503, 504, 522, 524, 408, 429],
        # 'DUPEFILTER_DEBUG': True,

        # 'DUPEFILTER_CLASS': 'scrapy.dupefilters.BaseDupeFilter',
        'DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES': {
            'UN.middlewares.UnDownloaderMiddleware': None,
            # 'scrapy_fake_useragent.middleware.RandomUserAgentMiddleware': 400,
        },
        # Add any other custom settings you want to modify here
    }

    # rules = (
    #     Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=r'https://www.unicef-irc.org/publications/\d+-.*\.html'), callback='parse_item'),
    # )

    def start_requests(self):
        # Create an instance of the UserAgent class
        user_agent = UserAgent()
        # Yield a request for the first page
        headers = {'User-Agent': user_agent.random}
        yield scrapy.Request(self.start_urls[0], headers=headers, callback=self.parse_total_results)

    def parse_total_results(self, response):
        # Extract the total number of results for the search and update the start_urls list with all the page URLs
        total_results = int(response.css('span.FT-result::text').get().strip())
        self.max_pages = math.ceil(total_results / 12)
        # self.max_pages = 3
        self.start_urls = [f'https://www.unicef-irc.org/publications/?page={page}' for page in
                           range(1, self.max_pages + 1)]
        print(f'Total results: {total_results}, maximum pages: {self.max_pages}')
        time.sleep(1)
        # Yield a request for all the pages by iteration
        user_agent = UserAgent()
        for i, url in enumerate(self.start_urls):
            headers = {'User-Agent': user_agent.random}
            yield scrapy.Request(url, headers=headers, callback=self.parse_links, priority=len(self.start_urls) - i)

    def parse_links(self, response):
        # print('im here')
        # Extract all links that abide by the rule
        links = LinkExtractor(allow=r'https://www\.unicef-irc\.org/publications/\d+-[\w-]+\.html').extract_links(
            response)
        for y, link in enumerate(links):
            headers = {'User-Agent': UserAgent().random}
            try:
                # print(link.url)
                yield scrapy.Request(link.url, headers=headers, callback=self.parse_item,
                                     errback=lambda err: print('Error', err), priority=len(links) - y)

            except Exception as e:
                print(f'Error sending request for {link.url}: {str(e)}')

    def parse_item(self, response):
        # Your item parsing code here
        # user_agent = response.request.headers.get('User-Agent').decode('utf-8')
        # print(f'User-Agent used for request: {user_agent}')
        print('print inside parse_item')
        print(response.url)
        time.sleep(1)

        title = response.css('div.headTitle h1::text').get(default='').strip()
        publication_date = response.css('p:contains("Publication date:") span::text').get(default='')
        authors_div = response.css('div.author').get(default=[])
        if authors_div:
            authors = [author.strip() for author in response.css('div.author a::text, div.author::text').getall() if
                       author and author.strip()]
...
```

my flow is correct and once i reach the yield with callback=self.parse_item i am supposed to get the url printed inside my parse_item method but it doesnt reach it at all its like the function is not being called at all?

i have no errors and no exception and the previous print statements are both printing the same url correctly that abide by the Link Extractor rule:

```
print before yield
https://www.unicef-irc.org/publications/1224-playing-the-game-framework-and-toolkit-for-successful-child-focused-s4d-development-programmes.html
https://www.unicef-irc.org/publications/1224-playing-the-game-framework-and-toolkit-for-successful-child-focused-s4d-development-programmes.html
print after yield

print before yield
https://www.unicef-irc.org/publications/1220-reopening-with-resilience-lessons-from-remote-learning-during-covid19.html
https://www.unicef-irc.org/publications/1220-reopening-with-resilience-lessons-from-remote-learning-during-covid19.html
print after yield
```

so why is the parse_item method not being called?

i tried to change the parse_item name i tried different print statements, i tried different LinkExtractor rule but its all the same and i am not gettings any errors or exceptions

this is my full output after i stop it:

````
2023-03-13 11:47:53 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Scrapy 2.8.0 started (bot: UN)
2023-03-13 11:47:53 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Versions: lxml 4.9.1.0, libxml2 2.9.12, cssselect 1.1.0, parsel 1.7.0, w3lib 2.0.1, Twisted 22.10.0, Python 3.10.7 (tags/v3.10.7:6cc6b13, Sep  5 2022, 14:08:36) [MSC v.1933 64 bit (AMD64)], pyOpenSSL 22.
1.0 (OpenSSL 3.0.5 5 Jul 2022), cryptography 38.0.1, Platform Windows-10-10.0.19045-SP0
2023-03-13 11:47:53 [scrapy.crawler] INFO: Overridden settings:
{'AUTOTHROTTLE_ENABLED': True,
 'AUTOTHROTTLE_MAX_DELAY': 75,
 'AUTOTHROTTLE_START_DELAY': 10,
 'BOT_NAME': 'UN',
 'DOWNLOAD_DELAY': 5,
 'NEWSPIDER_MODULE': 'UN.spiders',
 'RETRY_TIMES': 5,
 'SPIDER_MODULES': ['UN.spiders']}
2023-03-13 11:47:53 [py.warnings] WARNING: C:\Users\10229953\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\scrapy\utils\request.py:232: ScrapyDeprecationWarning: '2.6' is a deprecated value for the 'REQUEST_FINGERPRINTER_IMPLEMENTATION' setting.  

It is also the default value. In other words, it is normal to get this warning if you have not defined a value for the 'REQUEST_FINGERPRINTER_IMPLEMENTATION' setting. This is so for backward compatibility reasons, but it will change in a future ver
sion of Scrapy.

See the documentation of the 'REQUEST_FINGERPRINTER_IMPLEMENTATION' setting for information on how to handle this deprecation.
  return cls(crawler)

2023-03-13 11:47:53 [scrapy.utils.log] DEBUG: Using reactor: twisted.internet.selectreactor.SelectReactor
2023-03-13 11:47:53 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] INFO: Telnet Password: f7abccb5ae9d7592
2023-03-13 11:47:53 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled extensions:
['scrapy.extensions.corestats.CoreStats',
 'scrapy.extensions.telnet.TelnetConsole',
 'scrapy.extensions.feedexport.FeedExporter',
 'scrapy.extensions.logstats.LogStats',
 'scrapy.extensions.throttle.AutoThrottle']
2023-03-13 11:47:53 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled downloader middlewares:
['scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpauth.HttpAuthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.downloadtimeout.DownloadTimeoutMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.defaultheaders.DefaultHeadersMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.useragent.UserAgentMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry.RetryMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.MetaRefreshMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpcompression.HttpCompressionMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.RedirectMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.cookies.CookiesMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpproxy.HttpProxyMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.stats.DownloaderStats']
2023-03-13 11:47:53 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled spider middlewares:
['scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror.HttpErrorMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite.OffsiteMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.referer.RefererMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.urllength.UrlLengthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.depth.DepthMiddleware']
2023-03-13 11:47:54 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled item pipelines:
['UN.pipelines.DuplicateItemsPipeline']
2023-03-13 11:47:54 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
2023-03-13 11:47:54 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2023-03-13 11:47:54 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] INFO: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6024
2023-03-13 11:47:55 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.unicef-irc.org/publications/> (referer: None)
Total results: 1182, maximum pages: 99
2023-03-13 11:48:03 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.unicef-irc.org/publications/?page=1> (referer: https://www.unicef-irc.org/publications/)
2023-03-13 11:48:08 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.unicef-irc.org/publications/?page=2> (referer: https://www.unicef-irc.org/publications/)
2023-03-13 11:48:08 [scrapy.dupefilters] DEBUG: Filtered duplicate request: <GET https://www.unicef-irc.org/publications/1687-unlocking-learning.html> - no more duplicates will be shown (see DUPEFILTER_DEBUG to show all duplicates)
2023-03-13 11:48:14 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.unicef-irc.org/publications/?page=3> (referer: https://www.unicef-irc.org/publications/)
2023-03-13 11:48:22 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.unicef-irc.org/publications/?page=4> (referer: https://www.unicef-irc.org/publications/)
2023-03-13 11:48:26 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.unicef-irc.org/publications/?page=5> (referer: https://www.unicef-irc.org/publications/)
2023-03-13 11:48:31 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.unicef-irc.org/publications/?page=6> (referer: https://www.unicef-irc.org/publications/)
2023-03-13 11:48:35 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.unicef-irc.org/publications/?page=7> (referer: https://www.unicef-irc.org/publications/)
2023-03-13 11:48:42 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.unicef-irc.org/publications/?page=8> (referer: https://www.unicef-irc.org/publications/)
2023-03-13 11:48:47 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.unicef-irc.org/publications/?page=9> (referer: https://www.unicef-irc.org/publications/)
2023-03-13 11:48:53 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.unicef-irc.org/publications/?page=10> (referer: https://www.unicef-irc.org/publications/)
2023-03-13 11:48:55 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 11 pages (at 11 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2023-03-13 11:48:57 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.unicef-irc.org/publications/?page=11> (referer: https://www.unicef-irc.org/publications/)
2023-03-13 11:49:03 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.unicef-irc.org/publications/?page=12> (referer: https://www.unicef-irc.org/publications/)
2023-03-13 11:49:07 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.unicef-irc.org/publications/?page=13> (referer: https://www.unicef-irc.org/publications/)
2023-03-13 11:49:15 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.unicef-irc.org/publications/?page=14> (referer: https://www.unicef-irc.org/publications/)
2023-03-13 11:49:22 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.unicef-irc.org/publications/?page=15> (referer: https://www.unicef-irc.org/publications/)
2023-03-13 11:49:27 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.unicef-irc.org/publications/?page=16> (referer: https://www.unicef-irc.org/publications/)
2023-03-13 11:49:34 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.unicef-irc.org/publications/?page=17> (referer: https://www.unicef-irc.org/publications/)
2023-03-13 11:49:38 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.unicef-irc.org/publications/?page=18> (referer: https://www.unicef-irc.org/publications/)```


as you can see it is crawling all pages first without firing parse_item callback i tried changing the max_pages to something hardcoded like 3 or 4 and the same thing happens it crawls all the pages first then it calls parse_item.
````

Comment: post your log output

Comment: @Alexander is this what you mean? i edited my post, i am manually stopping the script because i dont want to crawl al pages then go into parse_item i want to go into parse_item for every page if it has links that abide by the rules of LinkExtractor

Comment: yah that is what I was referring to but it doesn't actually help much.  Please create a [mre]

Comment: @Alexander i reddited my code im not sure if this is what you mean, i added the class and abit more of code, once i reach parse_links and link.url in my callback=slef.parse_item does not fire the function with the url that i got but it does after getting all the links in the end of all pages..

Comment: well your `parse_item`  isn't a generator. If turning into a generator doesn't help then create an actual [mre]